# ZFS rollback on Ubuntu 20.10 failing - 'rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_': dataset already exists

Tags: zfs, 20.10

When I tried to restore an earlier snapshot, I was confronted with this exact error message:

```
No key available with this passphrase.

Command: /sbin/zfs clone -o canmount=noauto -m com.ubuntu.zsys:bootfs=yes -o mountpoint=/ rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66@autozsys_o8o5p5 rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_
Message: cannot create 'rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_': dataset already exists
Error: 1

Failed to clone snapshot.
Make sure that the any problems are corrected and the make sure that the dataset 'rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_' exists and is bootable
```

I tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas. Do I have have to rename this dataset with `zfs`? Here is the output of `zfs list` if that is of any help:

```
NAME                                               USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
bpool                                             1,04G   730M       96K  /boot
bpool/BOOT                                        1,03G   730M       96K  none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_2ips66                          1,03G   730M      217M  /boot
rpool                                              169G   745G      192K  /
rpool/ROOT                                        26,4G   745G      192K  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_                                12,1G   745G     7,07G  /
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66                          14,3G   745G     7,10G  /
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/srv                       352K   745G      192K  /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/usr                      9,49G   745G      192K  /usr
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/usr/local                9,49G   745G     9,47G  /usr/local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/var                      4,66G   745G      192K  /var
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/var/games                 192K   745G      192K  /var/games
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/var/lib                  4,19G   745G     3,13G  /var/lib
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/var/lib/AccountsService  1,84M   745G      216K  /var/lib/AccountsService
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/var/lib/NetworkManager   4,04M   745G      264K  /var/lib/NetworkManager
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/var/lib/apt              95,8M   745G     78,8M  /var/lib/apt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/var/lib/dpkg              206M   745G     63,9M  /var/lib/dpkg
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/var/log                   476M   745G      279M  /var/log
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/var/mail                  192K   745G      192K  /var/mail
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/var/snap                 2,18M   745G      784K  /var/snap
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/var/spool                5,57M   745G     2,67M  /var/spool
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_2ips66/var/www                   192K   745G      192K  /var/www
rpool/USERDATA                                     142G   745G      192K  /
rpool/USERDATA/root_kyouli                        7,08M   745G      448K  /root
rpool/USERDATA/<user>_kyouli                       142G   745G      133G  /home/<user>
rpool/keystore                                     518M   746G     48,1M  -
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zfs-linux/+bug/1894329). Rollbacks don't work because of that bug, at least for some people. A fix is in the works as I understand it.

I think you can remove the dataset without suffix (`ubuntu_`) with `zfs destroy`. At least it worked for me. And I guess we need to wait for the fix.