# Undeletable phantom directories with question marks in ls causing ZFS mount to fail

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, data-recovery, zfs

After an `apt` updgrade, I ran into some boot issues involving systemd dependency cycles (like in [zfs-linux#1875577](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zfs-linux/+bug/1875577)). So, since I’m running 20.10 on ZFS (with encryption), I decided to [revert the system state using the GRUB ZFS history entries](https://didrocks.fr/2020/05/28/zfs-focus-on-ubuntu-20.04-lts-zsys-general-principle-on-state-management/#reverting-to-a-previous-system-state). However, this apparently caused me to run into [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zfs-linux/+bug/1894329) with the `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_` dataset (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1291509)), and so I still can’t boot my system. Moreover, now mounting `/var/lib/NetworkManager` and `/var/lib/apt` was failing during the boot process.

I tried to see if I can investigate by mounting the ZFS file system from a live USB session:

```
zpool export -a
zpool import -N -R /mnt rpool
zpool import -N -R /mnt bpool
cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/zvol/rpool/keystore keystore
mkdir -p /run/keystore/rpool
mount /dev/mapper/keystore /run/keystore/rpool
zfs load-key -a
zfs mount rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_<UUID>
zfs mount bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_<UUID>
zfs mount -a
```

The result of `zfs mount -a` showed similar errors as while booting:

```
cannot mount '/mnt/var/lib/NetworkManager': failed to create mountpoint
cannot mount '/mnt/var/lib/apt': failed to create mountpoint
```

Trying to see what’s going on, I get these strange question marks in `ls` for `/mnt/var/lib/NetworkManager` and `/mnt/var/lib/apt`, but also access errors for these paths.

```
$ ls -ahl /mnt/var/lib/
ls: cannot access '/mnt/var/lib/NetworkManager': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/mnt/var/lib/apt': No such file or directory
total 718K
drwxr-xr-x 80 root          root          80 Nov 18 00:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root          root          18 Oct 22 14:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root           4 Oct 22 14:01 AccountsService
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Jan 31  2019 acpi-support
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Dec  1 13:38 alsa
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root           5 Nov 18 00:54 apache2
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root           4 Dec  1 11:25 app-info
d?????????  ? ?             ?              ?            ? apt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           4 Nov 19 21:58 aptitude
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          27 Oct 22 14:12 aspell
drwxr-xr-x  2 avahi-autoipd avahi-autoipd  2 Oct 22 14:09 avahi-autoipd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           5 Nov 15 23:06 binfmts
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root           3 Nov 15 13:40 bluetooth
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Jun 16 14:01 boltd
drwxrwxrwt  2 root          root           2 Jul 27 15:38 BrlAPI
drwxr-xr-x  4 colord        colord         6 Nov 15 15:01 colord
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           4 Dec  1 11:25 command-not-found
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Nov 15 15:01 dbus
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Aug 12 09:33 dhcp
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root           5 Oct 22 14:08 dictionaries-common
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root           4 Dec  1 12:05 dkms
drwxr-xr-x  7 root          root          18 Dec  1 12:06 dpkg
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root           3 Oct 22 14:02 emacsen-common
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Apr 16  2020 fprint
drwxr-xr-x  6 root          root           7 Nov 15 23:05 fwupd
drwxr-xr-x  5 gdm           gdm            6 Dec  1 13:30 gdm3
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root           3 Nov 15 22:59 gems
drwxr-xr-x  2 geoclue       geoclue        2 Feb 28  2020 geoclue
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root           4 Oct 22 14:03 ghostscript
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Jun  9 20:50 git
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root           4 Oct 22 14:04 grub
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Jun 22 10:09 hp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           6 Nov 25 11:32 initramfs-tools
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Oct 22 14:02 ispell
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root           3 Oct 22 14:05 libreoffice
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root           3 Nov 15 22:59 libxml-sax-perl
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root           3 Oct 22 14:12 locales
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Nov 30 23:00 logrotate
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Oct 22 14:10 man-db
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Oct 16 15:40 misc
d?????????  ? ?             ?              ?            ? NetworkManager
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root           3 Oct 22 14:10 openvpn
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Dec  1 12:55 os-prober
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Dec  1 13:31 PackageKit
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           8 Nov 19 21:57 pam
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root           4 Nov 15 23:35 php
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Nov 15 15:01 plymouth
drwx------  3 root          root           3 Oct 22 13:59 polkit-1
drwx------  2 root          root           2 Oct 22 13:59 private
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Oct 22 13:59 python
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Sep  8 18:15 realmd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           4 Nov 19 21:57 sgml-base
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root           5 Nov 15 15:18 shim-signed
drwxr-xr-x 24 root          root          26 Dec  1 13:30 snapd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Aug  6 15:42 snmp
drwxr-xr-x 10 root          root          10 Oct 22 14:09 sss
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root           3 Oct 22 13:59 sudo
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Feb 28  2020 synaptic
drwxr-xr-x 12 root          root          13 Nov 15 15:01 systemd
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root           5 Nov 15 22:59 tex-common
drwxr-xr-x  9 root          root          16 Nov 18 00:54 texmf
drwx--S---  3           127           135  9 Dec  1 13:38 tor
drwxr-xr-x  2 tss           tss            2 Dec  3  2019 tpm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Nov 15 13:46 ubiquity
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Sep  1 17:14 ubuntu-advantage
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Nov 15 15:01 ubuntu-drivers-common
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Nov 28 13:17 ubuntu-release-upgrader
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          21 Nov 18 01:28 ucf
drwx------  2 root          root           3 Dec  1 13:30 udisks2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Aug  5 12:03 unattended-upgrades
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Jul 23 19:50 update-manager
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root           6 Dec  1 12:06 update-notifier
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           6 Dec  1 13:05 upower
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           2 Jul 27 16:30 usb_modeswitch
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Oct 22 14:02 usbutils
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root           3 Oct 22 13:59 vim
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Dec  1 13:30 whoopsie
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Oct 22 14:10 xfonts
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           3 Oct 22 14:04 xkb
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root           6 Oct 22 14:11 xml-core
```

Trying to access or delete these paths claims that no such files exist, while trying to `mkdir` claims that the files do already exist! (This is why the mount point cannot be created.)

```
$ ls /mnt/var/lib/NetworkManager
ls: cannot access '/mnt/var/lib/NetworkManager': No such file or directory
$ rm /mnt/var/lib/NetworkManager
rm: cannot remove '/mnt/var/lib/NetworkManager': No such file or directory
$ rmdir /mnt/var/lib/NetworkManager
rmdir: failed to remove '/mnt/var/lib/NetworkManager': No such file or directory
$ mkdir /mnt/var/lib/NetworkManager
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/var/lib/NetworkManager’: File exists
```

What happened here? How can I get rid of these path entries?